# 2017 Jeep Patriot 2.0 with cvt trans

Tags: jeep, cvt-transmission, patriot

Check transmission fluid reads 70 mm cold and hot after driving put through gears did everything you're supposed to do tried this multiple times still reads the same 70 mm no matter if cold or hot and yes I'm on a flat surface and yes I did this with the car running and Park after taking it for a drive and letting it get nice and hot can anyone help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Usually if fluid reading (engine oil, gearbox oil, brake fluid, etc) is stable after being correctly measured with no apparent external leaks, one just adds fluid to bring the reading up to the specified level. What is your question?